# Docker on Windows 10 Crashing

Tags: windows, docker

I'm on windows 10 and I'm encountering Docker on Windows crashing on startup.

I just installed docker on windows and have a couple of containers spinning up (last night). I've been able to use it but after reboot, or shutdown, this was the behaviour ever since. Pretty unstable.

[image: crashing on startup]

It looks like this and terminates after a while without any prompt of an error.

More info that I have Hyper-V installed on my machine and "Use the WSL 2 based engine" option enabled on docker.

[image: Features]

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I was able to solve this by:

1. Going to Apps & Features
2. Search for Ubuntu (or any linux distro you've installed)
3. Click on it and navigate to Advance options
4. Click on Reset button.

Also, try to trial and error which docker on windows version is stable with your system.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please know that resetting the app will delete all the information in your docker: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390012/i-reset-ubuntu-on-wsl-with-setting-apps-ubuntu-reset-now-all-my-files-i

I feel it's irresponsible to offer "just reset it" as a catch all response to these questions without any warning about it's effects or reasoning why it'll fix the specific problem.